# Does the BigQuery API offer a way to retrieve info on scheduled queries?

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks, api

Using the BigQuery C# API, I can [retrieve a list of job IDs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#list_jobs):

```
BigQueryClient  _client = BigQueryClient.Create(...);
...
foreach (var page in _client.ListJobs(projectId).AsRawResponses())
    if (page.Jobs != null)  // This does happen occasionally
        foreach (var job in page.Jobs)
            yield return job.Id;
```

This seems to give me all jobs ever run (or at least within some significant time horizon; it's tens of thousands of records).  Still, I'd like to get the details for some jobs and see if I'm at least on the right track.  I can retrieve a `BigQueryJob` object using `BigQueryClient.GetJob()` (there's no C# doc, but [the Java sample code is similar](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-get-job#bigquery_get_job-java)), but the information returned is very limited: current state, any errors encountered, some basic statistics, etc.  There's nothing about schedules.

Is there a separate command to retrieve details on scheduled queries?  I can't find any such methods in the client.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled queries, and data transfers in general, have a separate API and NuGet package:

```
Google.Cloud.BigQuery.DataTransfer.V1
```

Here's how you can get info on scheduled queries using this package:

```
_client = DataTransferServiceClient.Create();

var  request = new ListTransferConfigsRequest();
request.ParentAsProjectName = new ProjectName(projectId);
var  response = _client.ListTransferConfigs(request);

foreach (var rawTransfer in response)
    {
    Guid    id       = new Guid(rawTransfer.TransferConfigName.TransferConfigId);
    string  name     = rawTransfer.DisplayName;
    bool    enabled  = !rawTransfer.Disabled;
    string  user     = rawTransfer.OwnerInfo?.Email ?? "None";
    string  schedule = rawTransfer.Schedule;
    string  pubSub   = rawTransfer.NotificationPubsubTopic;
    yield return (id, name, enabled, user, schedule, pubSub);
    }
```